# Elegant way to add a specific character after each char in a string

Tags: c#, string, linq, character

I want to print a string from the database to a page. In this database the string looks like this: "`!"§%&/`". In my page it should look like this: "`! " § % & /`" (space between the chars).

I know it's possible with a simple `foreach` loop and also with the Aggregate function of Linq.

Foreach loop:

```
var result = "";
foreach (var s in stringFromDb)
{
    result += s + " ";
}
result = result.Trim()
```

Aggregate function:

```
var result = stringFromDb.Aggregate("", (current, s) => current + (s + " ")).Trim();
```

The aggregate function is kinda unreadable so I will definitively not use it.
Isn't there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you use `string.Join` ?

```
var str = "!\"§%&/";
var result = string.Join(" ", str.ToCharArray())
```

Or without `ToCharArray` (suggested in comments)

```
 var result = string.Join<char>(" ", str)
```

Comment: Since .NET 4 you don't even need `ToCharArray`: `string.Join<char>(" ", str)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 string st= "!\"§%&/";
 var res = Regex.Replace(st, new string('.', 1), x => x.Value + " ");
```